# How to filter api results before the http response

Tags: c#, json, jsonp

I ran into blockade on a project of mine. I'm trying to make a C# UWP app that accesses the AviationStack flight tracker [api](https://aviationstack.com/documentation). I'm pretty new to the JavaScript side of this. I managed to get the JSON back and deserialize it and save it into objects, but it only provides 100 results per request, so I want to be able to filter the result based on user input. I know it's built-in to the API since the documentation has the following error example:

```
{
"error": {
  "code": "validation_error",
  "message": "Request failed with validation error",
  "context": {
     "flight_date": [
        {
           "key": "invalid_flight_date",
           "message": "The flight date must be a valid date in the format YYYY-MM-DD."
        }
     ]
  }}}
```

I'm guessing I need to look into the JSONP callback:

> The aviationstack API supports JSONP Callbacks. To use the JSONP functionality, simply append the callback parameter to your API endpoint URL and set it to a function name of your choice. If a function name is provided, the API will return your API response wrapped inside the tags of the function you specified.

If that's where I need to look could someone point how I can add a sample callback function that could for example filter results based on the condition ("departure">"iata":"EYK") to this HttpRequest:

```
class Program
{
    const string ACCESSKEY = "MY ACCESS KEY....";
    static string baseURL = "http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights";
    static Uri uri = new Uri($"{baseURL}?access_key={ACCESSKEY}");
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
        request.Method = "GET";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    ///...
    }
}
```

If not, please point me in the right direction.

Forgive me if all of that sounded like non-sense to you lol. I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

Derp, I looked more into it, the only thing I had to do was add to the HttpRequest parameters:

```
http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=MYKEY&dep_iata=SFO
```

Sorry for the headache.